# Unable to connect to my aws elasticache cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

I am not able to connect to my aws elasticache cluster from my local machine.
Is it possible to connect to the cluster from my local machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot connect to Elastic cluster through your local instance . You can connect only through EC2 instances .